# SQL Query: ships with second biggest gun size

Tags: sql, database

I need help with this query. For this problem we have two schemas about battleships and the battles they fought in:
     Ships(name, yearLaunched, country, numGuns, gunSize, displacement)
     Battles(ship, battleName, result)
the question is the following: write a query in which battleships had the guns with the second largest gun size. More precisely, find the ships whose gun size was exceeded by only one gun size, no matter how many other ships had that larger gun size. List the names of the ships and their gun size. 
 I attempted to solve the problem and my answer was the following:

```
Select smax.name, smax.gunSize
From   ships smax
Where ((select s.name,s.gunSize
                from Ships s
                where s.gunSize NOT EXISTS ( select ss.gunSize from ships ss where ss.gunSize >= ALL(select 
                ss1.gunSize from ships ss1))) AS temp) 
         AND smax.gunSize >= ALL (select temp.gunSize from ships temp)
```

Thank you for taking time to read this and answer !

Comment: SQL yes, but any specific dialect? MSSQL? MySQL? Oracle? Other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Select name, gunSize from ships
where gunSize=(
  select max(gunSize) as SecondBiggest from ships 
  where gunSize<(select max(gunSize) as Biggest from ships)
  )
```

**EDIT**: *Hint*: the `SecondBiggest` and `Biggest` aliases are used for clarifying what each subquery does.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Thank you all for your help. I appreciate !

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT name, gunSize
  FROM (SELECT name, gunSize, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY gunSize DESC) r)
 WHERE r = 2
```